# Initializing Object with nested form not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, nested-forms

I have a model of a brand that can have many products that can have many categories. I have a nested form to create products that permit nested attributes for creating categories. But I can make it work.

```
class Brand < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_many :products, dependent: :destroy

  validates :name,  presence: true,
                    length: { maximum: 50 }
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :brand
  has_many :categories, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :categories

  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }

  validates :brand_id, presence: true
  validates :name,     presence: true,
                       length: { maximum: 50 }
  private

    def product_params
      params.require(:product).permit(:name,
                                       categories_attributes: [:name, :price])
    end
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  has_many :units, dependent: :destroy

  validates :price,    presence: true
  validates :product_id, presence: true
  validates :name,       presence: true,
                         length: { maximum: 50 }
end
```

So my product controller is:

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @product = current_brand.products.new
    @product.categories.build
  end

  def create
    @product = current_brand.products.build(product_params)
    if @product.save
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

and my new view is like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@product) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages_products' %>

      <%= f.label :name, "Name:" %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
      <%= link_to_add_fields "Add Category", f, :categories %>

      <%= f.submit "Add Product", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

and my category partial is:

```
<fieldset>
  <%= f.label :name, "Category Name" %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.label :price, "Price" %>
  <%= f.text_field :price, class: 'form-control' %>
  <hr>
</fieldset>
```

I have the link_to_add_fields helper in my application helper:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
    id = new_object.object_id
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
      render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", f: builder)
    end
    link_to(name, '#', class: "add_fields", data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})
  end
end
```

That allows me to use some Javascript to add category fields with:

```
jQuery ->
  $('form').on 'click', '.add_fields', (event) ->
    time = new Date().getTime()
    regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
    $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
    event.preventDefault()
```

But when I try to add a product with any number of categories in this example 2, I fail to create the products and the categories. I get the error from my form and object error:

```
The form contains 1 error:
Categories product can't be blank
```

The params I get from this submition are:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"IO8GFcv1auFVh/ZNypONI78XQrY2Ntm07cMrrjmq51ogwppbsb1sNyN/ynKY+Pdb/lyniED9O6jFRkLKsvu2jQ==", "product"=>{"name"=>"Product Example", "categories_attributes"=>{"1467231299616"=>{"name"=>"Category Example 1", "price"=>"1234"}, "1467231300745"=>{"name"=>"Category Example 2", "price"=>"1234"}}}, "commit"=>"Agregar Producto", "controller"=>"products", "action"=>"create"}
```

I don't understand why the category and the product are not associating correctly.

Comment: if your having problems with the association, then more than likely the problem is going to be somewhere in your models.  I glanced over your models, and nothing really popped out at me, but do some research on ActiveRecord associations.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip let my check them out!

Comment: I added the strong params I use for products maybe in there is the problem

Answer (score 1):

After a while of experimenting I found that the answer is to remove the validation of product_id from the category model. Like this:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  has_many :units, dependent: :destroy

  validates :price,    presence: true
  validates :name,       presence: true,
                         length: { maximum: 50 }
end
```